# What drives the price of bitcoin, in other words, what makes it go up or down?

Tags: exchanges, price-volatility

I am interested in knowing what kind of events and news have a direct impact on the bitcoin prices besides the raw supply and demand.

Answer (score 1):

"The price" is established through supply and demand, by definition.

Speculators might temporarily skew supply or demand after reading some news or predicting/anticipating some event. Or simply by rumours and herd mentality (more often than not).

What those speculators react to you'd have to ask them and doesn't sound like an on topic question here. It's not related to Bitcoin anyway, as it's the same for any other market.

One likely upcoming drop in supply is coming around 2016-07-26 when the block reward is going to halve again.

Comment: Saying that something is likely to change the price is a good way of indeed making that happen :)

Comment: Well to be exact i didn't say likely change in price. I said likely drop in supply. And tbh without thinking about or intending to say anything about the price. But reading it back now i see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a burgeoning stream of academic papers that study the impact of different kinds of factors on the exchange rate of Bitcoin (primarily BTC against USD).

One of the best studies that I suggest you look at is "What are the main drivers of the Bitcoin price?" by Kristoufek (2014).

There the author implements a wavelet coherence analysis to assess the impact of a big set of economic, transaction, technical and interest-related factors.

http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0123923